# Core data fetch is crashing with error "Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"

Tags: swift, core-data

We have a coredata **User** entity with the schema as below -

```swift
name String
aliases Transformable
```

**Note:** aliases is an String array.

The fetch code is like this -

```swift
var userDetails:[User]?

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName:"User")
userDetails = try self.viewContext.fetch(request) as? [User]
```

The fetch request is intermittently crashing with the below errors -

> Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
> type
>
> Expected User but found _NSCoreTypesetterLayoutCache
>
> Fatal error: NSArrav element failed to match the Swift Arrav Element
> type
>
> Expected NSFetchRequestResult but found NSAsynchronousFetchResult
>
> Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Rather then using *objective-c-ish* transformable decode the string array from and to JSON (String). There are many benefits for example it’s searchable in a predicate.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. It is difficult to understand what is the problem with the current information provided, try providing also the code in `User`, and if possible also the schema of the database.

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce the crash? You should be specifying the request as `NSFetchRequest<User>`, not `<NSFetchRequestResult>`. Why is your entity called `User` but the thing in your error message is `UserProfile`?

Comment: Schema of User is provided. The crash is intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your fetch request like this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
```

The `fetchRequest` method is auto-generated (unless you have opted out).
The key is putting your entity class in the angle brackets.

Comment: The above fix worked till that line but the crash got shifted to another line. The reason for crash is that the fetched **userDetails** also contain __NSCFData along with User objects. Any idea why the fetch request returns a data object?

Comment: I can't tell from the given information. Maybe look through theses examples and see if you can draw something from them:  https://www.advancedswift.com/fetch-requests-core-data-swift/